# Stuck SRAM dub crankset

Tags: maintenance, crankset, sram

I'm having trouble removing my drive side crank from the spindle I have already taken out the 8mm bolt and undone the preload ring on the non drive side it seems stuck on the end of the spindle. Please help. Any suggestions for how to get it off?

Comment: Just keep turning the 8mm bolt. It will come off eventually

Comment: @ArtGertner I know I have to be nice but it's tough because it's like you didn't read the question at all. Perhaps I'm just too sensitive about answers in comments

Comment: Hi @Swifty, no need to be offended. Perhaps I did not read the question carefully  enough, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

The description makes it sound like either the extraction cap is absent (they sometimes vibrate loose or otherwise go missing in action), or you took it off. The intention is for the extraction cap to be in place as you unthread the crank bolt. The crank bolt then rams into the extraction cap, which pulls the crank off the end of the spindle. It's a press fit so it's supposed to be stuck there until the press fit is undone.

If the cap is gone, you can get a new one in a new Dub crank bolt and cap set.